# How to put a query using cursor loader?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

this is sqlite query and need a use in cursor loader.
select * from triphistory where  _startdate  > date('now','-8 days');

i try this but not working code given below . please check this.

```
        c = new CursorLoader(
                this,
                HollaContractClass.Hollas.TRIP_HISTORY_URI,
                PROJECTION,
                HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.STATUS
                        + " =? AND "
                        + HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
                        + " >?",
                new String[] { "finished", "date('now','-8 days')" },
                HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
                        + " asc");
```

but it return 0 ..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL parameters (`?`) are for strings that are not to be interpreted in any way.

The values in the start date column are compared against the literal string `date('now','-8 days')`.

To execute the `date` function, you have to write it directly into the SQL string:

```
c = new CursorLoader(
        ...
                + HollaContractClass.Hollas.HollaTripHistoryColumns.START_DATE
                + " > date('now','-8 days')",
        new String[] { "finished", },
```